# Copying multiple binary files to one single binary file

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, window

I have two binary file (`macID.bin.bin`, `facDflttemp.bin`) that need to copy to single binary file (`facDflt.bin`).

Below are the command that can be executed using the java API.

```
"CMD /c copy /b " + "\"" +"C:\\Program Files\\Project\\GS\\3_5_5\\macID.bin.bin"
 + "\"" + "\"" + " + C:\\Program Files\\Project\\GS\\3_5_5\\facDflttemp.bin" + "
\"" + "\"" + " C:\\Program Files\\Project\\GS\\3_5_5\\facDflt.bin" + "\""
```

I tried using the `JAVA API` but it give the error message:

> 0 file(s) copied. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

Please provide a better solution to execute above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check code below.
it works for me.

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("CMD /c COPY /b \"D:\\1\\1.bin\" + \"D:\\1\\2.bin\" \"D:\\1\\3.bin\"");

    }
}
```

in your case use

```
"CMD /c copy /b  \"C:\\Program Files\\Project\\GS\\3_5_5\\macID.bin.bin\" + \"C:\\Program Files\\Project\\GS\\3_5_5\\facDflttemp.bin\" \"C:\\Program Files\\Project\\GS\\3_5_5\\facDflt.bin\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Java code :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

Comment: I tried above solution but give the error message:                     0 file(s) copied.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. please let me know where the syntax issue.

Comment: than you should mention in question, now please give error.